# LED detector application for open and short circuit of 10K value thermistor

Tags: led, thermistor

I am using an application where eight 10K thermistors wires are connected to a wearable device. The thermistors are stiched to the wearable device. We can determine the open and
short circuit of the thermistor using a multimeter if there is any open or short in the circuit.

But to determine the open and short in the circuit I want to use LEDs for the application.
The bottleneck is the thermistors are of 10K value. Can anyone suggest design for this application.

Regards,
Kumar

Comment: How do you read the thermistor value?

Comment: you could use a LED to indicate the state of a circuit, but how would you use a LED to detect the state of the circuit?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you measure voltage across a thermistor to get the temperature value.

**1. If the thermistors are connected in "divider mode":**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8pzrB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this case, you measure zero value if the thermistor is shorted, and full scale value if the thermistor went open.

**2. If the thermistors are connected in "constant-current" mode:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnJ7gx.png)</sup>

In this case, just like in divider mode, you should measure zero value if the thermistor is shorted, or full scale value if the thermistor is open (or not present/connected).

**3. If the thermistors are connected in "comparator mode":** The thermistors are connected in divider mode but the divider's voltage is compared to a constant reference. This method is preferred to detect an over- or under-temperature case rather than measuring an actual temperature with some accuracy. If this is how your thermistors are connected then things get complicated. Without any schematic it may not be possible to suggest a way.